# Determining if a matrix is diagonalizable in the R Programming Language

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix and I would like to know if it is diagonalizable. How do I do this in the R programming language?

Comment: plesae ask your question on a relevant maths forum...

Comment: It's OK, they're expected. 
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-flash-mobs/

Comment: @Mitch: It's a programming question. R is a programming language.

Comment: @jalf: I agree. The implementation of a statistical method in a given language is certainly a programming question. If the question had been "how do I tell if a matrix is diagonalizable?"  Then it would be a stats question.

Comment: @JD Long: Diagonalisation has *nothing* in particular to do with stats. It may be applicable in advanced stats, but is a subject of study in pure mathematics in its own right.

Comment: @noldorin good point! I should have said "the implementation of any method in a given language is certainly a programming question." You are correct that the topic here is much more general than stats. I was responding to the assertion that this was not a proper programming question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a given matrix, m, then one way is the take the eigen vectors times the diagonal of the eigen values times the inverse of the original matrix. That should give us back the original matrix. In R that looks like:

```
m <- matrix( c(1:16), nrow = 4)
p <- eigen(m)$vectors
d <- diag(eigen(m)$values)
p %*% d %*% solve(p)
m
```

so in that example `p %*% d %*% solve(p)` should be the same as `m`

Comment: That's a good point. To answer the original question (to check for diagonalizability of matrix m): 

1) compute the eigenvector matrix p = eigen(m)$vectors
2) check that the eigenvector matrix p is invertible (i.e., solve(p) does not result in error). If yes, then it's diagonalizable, and the unitary action is P. If not, then it is not diagonalizable. 

Why? Because invertibility means that the dimension of the direct product of the eigenspaces is the same as the dimension of the original matrix, and this condition is necessary and sufficient for diagonalizability.

Comment: note if the matrix is symmetric then we don't need to solve(p) as eigenvectors of symmetric matrix are orthogonal and transpose of orthogonal matrix is its inverse. So we can write p %*% d %*% t(p). Just a potential optimization for the case when m = t(m)

Answer (score 5):

You can implement the full algorithm to check if the matrix reduces to a Jordan form or a diagonal one (see e.g., [this document](http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/diagonal/diagonal.html)). Or you can take the quick and dirty way: for an n-dimensional square matrix, use eigen(M)$values and check that they are n distinct values. For random matrices, this always suffices: degeneracy has prob.0.

P.S.: based on a simple observation by JD Long below, I recalled that a necessary and sufficient condition for diagonalizability is that the eigenvectors span the original space. To check this, just see that eigenvector matrix has full rank (no zero eigenvalue). So here is the code:

```
diagflag = function(m,tol=1e-10){
    x = eigen(m)$vectors
    y = min(abs(eigen(x)$values))
    return(y>tol)
}
# nondiagonalizable matrix 
m1 = matrix(c(1,1,0,1),nrow=2) 
# diagonalizable matrix
m2 = matrix(c(-1,1,0,1),nrow=2) 

> m1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    1

> diagflag(m1)
[1] FALSE

> m2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1    0
[2,]    1    1

> diagflag(m2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Don't you need to worry about exactly what distinct means when calculated with floating point math?

Comment: Yes, and that is where knowledge of the problem structure helps. If the matrix has certain random structures, e.g. gaussian iid, the one can claim certain distributional properties of eigenvalues (typically, uniform on the unit circle), and then implement simple tests for the null hypothesis that eigenvalues are identical. This paper is basically all I know about random matrices: http://tinyurl.com/eigenvalues. If nothing is known about the matrix, I'd try a few more heuristics..

P.S.: I love ggplot2!

Comment: Thanks for taking what little I knew and stretching it into a much better answer! Good job. This is exactly why I like StackOverflow; the good stuff floats to the top much more obviously than with a pure threaded discussion. (ggplot does, indeed, rock!)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [this page](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/02.html) for some basic discussion and code.  You'll need to search for "diagonalized" which is where the relevant portion begins.

Answer (score 0):

All symmetric matrices across the diagonal are diagonalizable by orthogonal matrices.  In fact if you want diagonalizability only by orthogonal matrix conjugation, i.e. D= P *A*P' where P' just stands for transpose then symmetry across the diagonal, i.e. A_{ij}=A_{ji}, is exactly equivalent to diagonalizability.

If the matrix is not symmetric, then diagonalizability means not D= P*A*P' but merely D=P*A*P^{-1} and we do not necessarily have P'=P^{-1} which is the condition of orthogonality.

you need to do something more substantial and there is probably a better way but you could just compute the eigenvectors and check rank equal to total dimension.

See [this discussion](https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-10/msg00090.html) for a more detailed explanation.